# Setting up variable constrains in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm having trouble setting up constraints.

This is the thing I am trying to achieve:
[image: screen shot]

I have 2 objects A and B. I want there there to be a maximum of 100 points between A and B if its a larger screen, or less if its a smaller screen.

Also, I want there to be a minimum of a 20 point margin from the main view controller. So on a smaller screen the minimum spacing will be 20 points, and on a larger screen the margin can be as wide as needs in order to satisfy the space between A and B at 100 points.

To illustrate how I want it to look on various screens:

**4 inch screen**

[image]

I want there to be a 20 point margin on either side and the middle (space between A and B) can be variable, i.e. 100 or less.

**5.5 inch screen**

[image]

The margins can be variable and expand as large as they need to, but the middle section (space between A and B) can be a maximum of 100.

Any help how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you insist on the constraints? What if you use simple if-then-else and based on the device's width you calculate the appropriate positions?

Comment: yeah, may be the way to go. I wouldn't mind doing this as a training exercise though.

Comment: Thats exactly what I tried (except I think you mean A-B horizontal space rather than training space). I get 'Inequality Constraint Ambiguity' for trainingMargin >= B.training + 20 and A.leading >= leadingMargin + 20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved with help from three dummy views and two width constrains with different priorities. I set up a test project to test my thought. check it out to see whether it's what you needed

https://github.com/dopcn/testSeg